# Is there a way to stop OnItemSaving events?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I have managed to stop `OnItemSaved` events being triggered via the use of

```
item.Editing.EndEdit(false,true);
```

This however still triggers `OnItemSaving` events. Is there a way to disable this as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using an `EventDisabler`:

```
using (new EventDisabler())
{
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Found here: [Temporarily disable events through the Sitecore API](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/12/temporarily-disable-events-through-the-sitecore-api)

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @Ruud van Falier's answer, it is worth noting that the `EventDisabler`, like the `SecurityDisable`, inherits from `IDisposable`. As such, you can create a property or local variable that is an `EventDisabler` and Sitecore Events will be disabled from the moment that the variable or property is initialized up until the moment when the `Dispose()` method is called.

For example, in the following class, events will be disabled from the time that the `Foo()` method is called until the time that the `Bar()` method is called.

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    private EventDisabler _eventDisabler;

    ...

    public void ToggleEventDisabler(bool eventDisablerOn)
    {
        _eventDisabler = eventDisablerOn ? new EventDisabler() : null;
    }

    public void Foo() 
    {
        ToggleEventDisabler(true); //turn on the event disabler

        ...do stuff...
    }

    public void Bar() 
    {
        ...do stuff...

        if (_eventDisabler != null) 
        {
            _eventDisabler.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but that doesn't mean you should.  Why not: 1) it's much less obvious to consumers of your class how, when and why the event disabling happens; 2) it's much less obvious which code is being executed within the scope of the disabler (what about other classes/methods/async callbacks?); 3) you will inevitably have code paths where the disabler is not Disposed - exception conditions and the like, at which point event management becomes non-deterministic.  The `using` statement version solves all these issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

Saving with

```
item.Editing.EndEdit(false, true);
```

or

```
item.Editing.EndEdit(true, true);
```

Does not raise item events. Internally it uses `using (new EventDisabler())` if silent = true;

Possibly a Sitecore bug in the version you were using at the time ?